Problems on Shell Sort (when gap = 1, the algorithm does not work)
I just started to learn algorithms, and found a problem with the Shell Sort algorithm.
I have written 2 versions by C#, but I believe it is easy to understand.
The 1st version, which works well, is as follows:
            while (gap > 0)
            {
                for (int i = gap; i < int_array.Length; i++)
                {
                    temp = int_array[i];
                    j = i - gap;
                    while (j >= 0 && int_array[j] > temp)
                    {
                        int_array[j + gap] = int_array[j];
                        j -= gap;
                    }
                    int_array[j + gap] = temp;
                }
                Console.Write("Gap is " + gap + ":");
                arr.DisplayItems();
                gap /= 2;
            }

Another version is:
            while (gap > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < int_array.Length; i++)
                {
                    j = i + gap;
                    temp = int_array[i];
                    while (j < int_array.Length && int_array[j] < temp)
                    {
                        int_array[j - gap] = int_array[j];
                        j += gap;
                    }
                    int_array[j - gap] = temp;
                }
                Console.Write("Gap is " + gap + ":");
                arr.DisplayItems();
                gap /= 2;
            }

This version will get stuck on sorting, and I could not find the reason.
The problem seems like: When gap = 1, the algorithm will sort only 1 time unlike other gaps(gap != 1).
This algorithm may work incorrectly on dealing with arrays when gap = 1. However, I could not understand that it seems working well when gap != 1.
I have read the answer in Stackoverflow Web: For full sorting, you have to repeat sort with gap = 1 while swapping occurs.
However, there is a new question. Why does it work well without repeating 'gap = 1' sort (as shown in the 1st version)?

The second version apparently intends to implement the algorithm in the opposite direction (compared to the first version): so it has the j loop iterating from left to right (increasing j) instead of right to left (decreasing j). This means that the insertion of temp happens to the right of i instead of the left of i. In other words, the gap-series will have its already sorted part at the right of i instead of the left of i.
All this was mirrored in the correct way... except in one place: the outer loop has two issues:

It is iterating in the wrong direction: it should have i go from right to left instead of left to right. The latter is what the first version does, but this should be mirrored as well.

It iterates more than necessary. Where the first version makes n - gap iterations, the second version makes n iterations.


So in the second version change this:
for (int i = 0; i < int_array.Length; i++)

to this:
for (int i = int_array.Length - 1 - gap; i >= 0; i--)

This will fix it. The reason it gives an unsorted result without this fix, is that the second version expects the section at the right of i to be already sorted (at steps of gap). But this is not generally the case when i iterates from left to right. i should iterate "away" from the already sorted part, growing it.

If my understanding is correct, this algorithm needs to create bigger and bigger sub-lists during iteration. However, in 2nd version, the sorted part narrows instead of growing like 1st version.
